# How to apply lowercase filter to GridView?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to apply lowercase filter to a gridview in Yii2 but unable to do so. Following is in my `search()` function:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', '`category`.`name`', $this->name])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like', '`category`.`sizes`', $this->sizes]);
```

I've also tried and modified `rules()` of my model this way:

```
['name', 'filter', 'filter'=>'strtolower']
```

but it didn't work.

TIA!

Comment: Try `strtolower($this->name)` in filter.

Answer (score 2):

Like Insane Skull has said you can add strtolower to the filter. But I think you should add it to both places. I do it like this:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'LOWER(name)', strtolower($this->keyword)]);
```